# Getting records that match two values under the same column (looking for shared associations)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I query a pandas dataframe to get the records that are associated with different values on under one column? It's essentially a co-query:

```
data = {"id": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "f", "f"],
        "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9, 11],
        "y": [1985, 1986, 1987, 1985, 1987, 1990, 1985, 1994, 1985, 1989, 1993, 1993]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   id   x     y
0   a   1  1985
1   a   2  1986
2   a   3  1987
3   b   1  1985
4   b   3  1987
5   c   5  1990
6   c   1  1985
7   d   7  1994
8   e   2  1985
9   f   4  1989
10  f   9  1993
11  f  11  1993
```

Given the above data I would like to get write a function `f(id1, id2, year=None)` that would look for `x` that are associated with both id1 and id2. So `f('a', 'b')` would return a data frame that corresponds to {x: [1, 3], y: [1985, 1987]}

```
   x     y
0  1  1985
1  3  1987
```

since both x=1 and x=3 are associated with both 'a' and 'b'.

Ideally I want to be able do this in a way which allows for filtering by the 'y' values as well. Also the dataframe is pretty big and this is a utility function that will be run often, so efficiency is important. I have thought of querying twice with different ids and merging:

```
In [15]: pd.merge(df.query('id=="a"'), df.query('id=="b"'), on='x')
Out[15]:
  id_x  x   y_x id_y   y_y
0    a  1  1985    b  1985
1    a  3  1987    b  1987
```

but I have a feeling that's not the most elegant and efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a bit moys answer and added the perf. 
You can do:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "f", "f"],
        "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9, 11],
        "y": [1985, 1986, 1987, 1985, 1987, 1990, 1985, 1994, 1985, 1989, 1993, 1993]})
def finder(ida,idb,year=None):
    g = data.groupby('id')
    g1 = set(g["x"].get_group(ida))
    g2 = set(g["x"].get_group(idb))
    if year:
        return data.loc[(data.x.isin(g1&g2)) & (data.id.isin([ida,idb])) & (data.y==year)]
    else :
        return data.loc[(data.x.isin(g1&g2)) & (data.id.isin([ida,idb])
```

It draws

> 4.42 ms ± 36.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In comparison, your current code draws

> 10.2 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The updated moys code draws :

> 10.6 ms ± 60.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Would it make sense to separate the groupby('id') from the rest to avoid it being run over and over again, since this function will be run hundreds of thousands of time

Comment: Yes if the element on which you want to group does not change it will definitely improve perf. I aslo edited as I made a slight mistake in the get group that was non dynamic

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the update, a quick note after checking the API docs, setting `sort=False` in groupby() is also supposed to be good if the performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should fulfill your primary need.

```
def f(x,y):
    g = df.groupby('id')
    g1 = g["x"].get_group(x).to_list()
    g2 = g["x"].get_group(y).to_list()
    return [val for val in g1 if val in g2]
f('a', 'b')
```

**Output**

`[1,3]`

---

In case the out put needed is the dataframe, the code below should work.

```
def f(x,y):
    g = df.groupby('id')
    if g.get_group(x).shape[0] >= g.get_group(y).shape[0]:
        res = g.get_group(x)[['x','y']].merge(g.get_group(y)[['x','y']], on=['x','y'],how = 'inner')
    else:
        res = g.get_group(y)[['x','y']].merge(g.get_group(x)[['x','y']], on=['x','y'],how = 'inner')
    return res
f('a', 'b')
```

**Output**

```
x   y
0   1   1985
1   3   1987
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I must have confused you a bit with the way I wrote about the expected result. I dont need lists _per se_. Does that change your answer?